# TCP windows full - intermittent issues in SSL handshake

Tags: ssl, tcp, wireshark, tcpdump

I am seeing an intermittent SSL handshake error. Looking at the tcp packets, it seems that the times when the SSL handshake fails, TCP options are missing. I have attached the wireshark screenshot for the success and failure scenario. Notice the difference in the [SYN,ACK] packet sent by the server. In success case, it has larger Window size (4380) as compared to 512 when it fails. It also has additional options like MSS and SACK_PERM.

Would anyone know why this would happen? It's the same server but it's sending different capabilities in separate scenarios. Any info in troubleshooting this issue will help. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It's curious, even the 4380. Should be at least 8192. But that doesn't cause handshake failures. What was the alert?

Comment: Content Type Alert (21). TLS 1.2 is being used.  From TLS RFC, decryption_failed_RESERVED(21),

https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246